# Example of Electrical Apparatus that draw leading VARS and Electrical Apparatus that draw lagging VARS

Tags: ac, reactive-power

I understand that an AC inductive circuit will draw lagging vars while a capacitive AC circuit will draw leading vars (ELI the ICE man), but what are some examples of real-life electrical apparatus that draw these types of Reactive Power.

Answer (score 2):

Induction motors are responsible for most lagging vars. Transformers, relays, solenoids and universal motors also contribute. The primary sources of leading vars are power factor compensation capacitors and wound-field synchronous generators.

Current distortion due to non-linear loads causes lagging power factor, but that is not quite the same thing as lagging vars.